# K array Tree Height using DFS with Recursion, is the code logic wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, recursive-datastructures

I feel embarrassed asking this question but I spent close to four hours trying to make sense of why this code works. My problem is that this code to me looks like it works to me when the longest path is selected the first time but not when sub-optimal path is selected first time. My guess is that this code works because when when the not longest path is selected the depth value and height resets and then the next path is selected??? Can someone please explain?

Picture:

[image: Example of outcome]

```
    '''
    For your reference:
    
    class TreeNode:
        def __init__(self):
            self.children = []

'''   
def find_height(root):
    global max
    max=0
    
    if not root:
        return 0
        
    traverse(root,0)  
    
    return max-1
        
def traverse(node, depth):
    
    global max
    
    depth +=1
    if depth>max:
        max=depth
        
    for child in node.children:
        traverse(child, depth)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, and it is like you say, but maybe it helps to just take a bit of abstraction. The code essentially traverses the whole tree. It does not really matter in which order it does that. In this code it performs a depth-first traversal, probably because that is the easiest to implement and has a small memory footprint. But it is not really relevant for understanding how it can return the length of the longest path.

Just note that the algorithm guarantees to visit *each* node and knows at which *depth* this node occurs. It should be clear that when you take the maximum depth of all the depths that you encounter during the traversal, that you have found the length of the longest path from the root, or in other words, the height of the tree.

The following statement makes sure the code always updates the maximum depth in light of the current depth:

```
if depth>max:
    max=depth
```

I should maybe also highlight that `depth` is a *local* variable, which belongs to one execution context of the function `traverse`. So each execution of the function creates a new instance of that variable. When you return out of a recursive call, the execution comes back to where you have a previous version of this variable. A recursive call does not modify the value of `depth` from where that call is made. So it truly reflects the depth of the current node (after `depth += 1` is executed)

In contrast, `max` is a *global* variable, and so there is only one version of that variable. And so the effect of `max=depth` persists also after a call of `traverse` terminates.

As a side note, many would say that modifying a global variable from inside a function is not ideal (it represents a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science))), and there are better ways to code this. The recursive function should better *return* the height of the subtree rooted in the node that is passed as argument. This also has as advantage that you don't need the `depth` argument, and you don't need a second function:

```py
def find_height(root):
    if not root:
        return 0
    # the height of the tree is 1 more than that of the tallest subtree below it
    return 1 + max(find_height(child) for child in root.children, default=0)
```